# How firebase real time database reads data?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat app where messages store in firebase realtime database. Now if i make a node shown below **(** chats-Between-A-and-B-Id are autogenerated chatroom keys **)**, so i want to know that when **user S** open chats with **user T** in chat app so Database will read only the messages stored in *chats-Between-S-and-T-Id* and will not read others chatroom messages **!?** am i right ? if yes then will it reduce the pricing?

```
chats-
      chats-Between-A-and-B-Id-
                 messageID1-…
                 messageID2-…
                 messageID3-…
                 ...
      chats-Between-o-and-p-Id-…
      chats-Between-s-and-t-Id-…
      chats-Between-x-and-y-Id-…
```

**OR**

If i store data like shown below then if **user S** open chats of **user T** in chat app so Database will read whole messages and

```
cahts-
      messageID1-…
      messageID2-…
      messageID3-…
      ...
```

sort them like (shown below) so it will read all messages and sort them and show in app to the user **!?** which will increase the pricing **?**

```
if(chat.getReceiver() == senderID && chat.getSender() == receiverId ||
   chat.getReceiver() == receiverId && chat.getSender() == senderID)
                          {
                             (mChatList as ArrayList<Chat>).add(chat) //show chats
                          }
```

*I  want  to  know  which  approach  can  save  my  money.*

**Edit**

I am using the 2nd approach (i got it from a chat app tutorial). Where we sort messages according to senders and receiver but after reading the answer of @sharath i get that if i go with this it will read every message from chat node and then sort them according to sender-reciver and if there are 1 million messages from all the users then it will read 1 million messages and sort only some of them only for 2 users! It will make me poor. So i am thinking about using the 1st approach where i will get messages from chat>>roomIdBetween2Users so it will ont read others chat and give me secure, maintainable and affordable databse.

And this is the image of my database here chats is parent node contains all the messages of all the users and sort them as i mentioned in the code for 2 users. There are already approximately 500+ messages in chats. And it will be so dangerous in future.[image]

Comment: It is more of a security thing than cost. You basically want the security rule to be as such that one can only access the message he has done with the other. So, chats of A and B stored as some_id_a_b can onl be accessed by A and B and neither of these users can access other users' chats as well. Limiting a node to two Ids instead of one, not mentioned in docs as well, I want similar security rule too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a little tricky situation to answer this without knowing your firebase DB structure. Am making an assumption and generalising this answer.

Firebase is a No SQL Database which stores data in tree structure or Parent child manner

Main important logic you should think of while developing anything with NoSQL databases are you need to create the Firebase DatabaseReference to the deepest node possible. Firebase queries and reads data which comes under the referenced node.

For example : if you have firebase structure as below

[See this image of Firebase sample structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2wy7.png)

If you want to access chats of User S, Create Reference to ID_User_S node.

note: If you create reference top node "Chats" then snapshot returns all child information under it

Regarding pricing : **Yes the lesser the data you read lesser the price you pay**. If you are referencing to deepest node possible you read lesser data. Try to optimise all firebase queries to reach to deepest node possible for creating a reference.

Now coming to your structure

```
chats-
      chats-Between-A-and-B-Id-
                 messageID1-…
                 messageID2-…
                 messageID3-…
                 ...
      chats-Between-o-and-p-Id-…
      chats-Between-s-and-t-Id-…
      chats-Between-x-and-y-Id-…
```

If you create a database reference to `Chats` node then each one trying to access the chat will read every child under it which includes others chats as well.
So for efficient usage create reference to `chats-Between-A-and-B-Id-` so that you can get exact list of messages under those 2 users

Comment: Hope this solution give you an idea of how firebase reads data. If you still have doubt please post your Demo Firebase Structure. So that I can help you out with appropriate solution

Comment: Hey @sharath your answer is so expressive Thanks for that . Now after reading your answer i got some clearance. So you mean that if i get reference of a child node like parentNode>> anyOneChildNode>> manyChildren so here if i take reference of anyone child node so it will not read others childNode so there will only be reads of that oneChildNode so i have to pay lesser than if i get reference of parentNode than sort child it means it read every chil then sort them and show me. It means i have read every child then whatever i sort them to get some of them. Now i have to pay more. Right?

Comment: Yes you got it right. If you create reference to top level parent node, your fetch query will read and return full tree structure which comes under it. That full data size is billable.So if you reach in inner most child node you can get which data exactly you need which in return avoid making you pay for unwanted data fetching. For additional information you can also use local Database for storing ones fetched data. So you may not have to fetch again and again.

Comment: Thank you! you are absolutely right and thanks for counselling me to use local database. I was also thinking about it to use SQL to save some important and non realtime data snapshots. I will try to implement them. I like the way of your cooperation, it's really appreciable .

Comment: Glad I could help you. Good Luck